# What can cause JSON serialization error during django bulk create

Tags: django

I am getting a weird error when performing a bulk_create. `MyModel` is a ForeignKey on `Item` model. It's code that was working perfectly fine. Just made some changes that clean up the objects to be bulk-created, the data on the item themselves is what has been there before.

`items` are unsaved instances of `Item` model. I see in the traceback that the `item` objects are being dumped to JSON at some point. I just don't understand why it's becoming problematic now when it wasn't before. Here is the traceback:

```
  File "/home/user/Documents/software/work/my-project/apps/myapp/importer.py", line 574, in bulk_write_to_db
    Item.objects.bulk_create(items, batch_size)
  File "/home/user/Documents/software/work/my-project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/Documents/software/work/my-project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 803, in bulk_create
    returned_columns = self._batched_insert(
  File "/home/user/Documents/software/work/my-project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1831, in _batched_insert
    self._insert(
  File "/home/user/Documents/software/work/my-project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1805, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/home/user/Documents/software/work/my-project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1822, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/Documents/software/work/my-project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py", line 246, in execute
    return self._record(super().execute, sql, params)
  File "/home/user/Documents/software/work/my-project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py", line 167, in _record
    return method(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/Documents/software/work/my-project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/home/user/Documents/software/work/my-project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/user/Documents/software/work/my-project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/Documents/software/work/my-project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/_json.py", line 78, in getquoted
    s = self.dumps(self.adapted)
  File "/home/user/Documents/software/work/my-project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/_json.py", line 72, in dumps
    return self._dumps(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type MyModel is not JSON serializable
```

**UPDATE**

Well, this was dumb, I had some data that was meant for a JSON field. I added some model instances to that data and completely forgot about it.

So if you experience such an error, there is data meant for a json field with model instances in it.

But I think it would be cool if Django would have told me what field it was.

Comment: Can you give us more info of your code and what changes you made?